# How to change Winamp's default skin to Bento?

Tags: winamp

If I install Winamp through automated means (e.g. Using http://ninite.com/), it is automatically installed using the default 'boxy' skin. I can't work out how to interface with this skin as easily as the new 'Bento' skin. In addition, there doesn't seem to be an option to download the Bento skin, or change the skin from Default to Bento without uninstalling and reinstalling it again.

Is there a menu option or a downloadable skin that is the default Bento skin? Or do I have to re-install to get this 'new default' skin?

Answer (score 1):

I have Winamp 5.6 installed and I can select the skin as follows:

On the **Options** menu, click **Preferences...**
On the **Winamp Preferences dialog box**, in the tree at left, click **Skins**
In the list of **Installed skins**, click **Bento**.

On my installation four installed skins are listed:

- Winamp Classic
- Winamp Modern
- Bento
- Big Bento

I use Big Bento myself. Clicking any of the skins immediately re-renders Winamp in that skin, there is no **Apply** button or such.

If it's not in the list of installed skins, perhaps I can send you the Bento skin from my system?

Comment: Did you use an automated installer like Ninite? That's what this post is about

Comment: No, apologies for lacking clarity there. 

It's one reason mind you I offered to send glasnt, the skin. They are just files in the winamp folder in the end. And it's also difficult to imagine that the ninite would do more or less than run the standard installer for a given package, but who knows.

Guess it's worth pointing out that the skins are stored in folders under "C:\Program Files\Winamp\Skins" or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\Skins" on a 64 bit machine if needing to diagnose or copy them.

Answer (score -1):

There is [Bento Classified](http://www.winamp.com/skin/bento-classified/170606) skin by Nullsoft. There is also [cpro skin](http://www.winamp.com/skin/cpro-city-night/195769) (the City Night color theme from Bento skin) if it suits you. If those don't meet your needs, I guess you'll have to reinstall Winamp.